# react-native-community / react-native-netinfo listners are not working on android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-community-netinfo

```js
 state = {
    isConnected: null,
  };
  
    componentDidMount() {
    this._netWorkConnection();
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._netWorkConnection();
  }
  
    _netWorkConnection = () => {
    NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
      console.log('Is connected?', state.isInternetReachable);

      const connection = state.isInternetReachable;

      this.setState(
        {
          isConnected: connection,
        },
        () => {
          if (this.state.isConnected === false) {
            this._showConnectionMessage();
          }
        },
      );
    });
  };

_showConnectionMessage() {
  Util.showMessage('No internet');
}
```

react-native-community / react-native-netinfo listners are not working on android but it is working fine in iOS 
though i have added internet permissions in my android manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

and has added `androidXCore = "1.0.2"` in build.gradle but no luck in android , below is my code

Comment: Please mention which version of React Native, and which android OS are you using.

Comment: react native version 0.61.5
all android devices
@NeetinSolanki

Comment: Have you removed 'supportLibVersion' property from android/build.gradle?

Comment: here it is  i have tried with both supportLibVersion and androidXCore but it is not working @NeetinSolanki

ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        // androidXCore = "1.0.2"
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }

Comment: You can only add only one at a time. Either add supportLibVersion or androidXCore, not both.

Comment: here is my build.gradle where I have used NetInfo, and it works perfectly. https://prnt.sc/rybb5d

Comment: i know that @NeetinSolanki ,
but i'm stating that neither it is working with androidXCore nor with supportLibVersion

Comment: hey @NeetinSolanki can you show me your code

Comment: Here it is, https://prnt.sc/rycwzl ,moreover I used version 4.1.1 of @react-native-community/netinfo, and RN version was 0.60.3.

Answer (score 1):

this code is fine
it is just not working in simulator while it is working fine on any other physical device